# How to use BitBucket Pipelines to update Google Cloud Compute Engine instance after a push?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-compute-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I've seen documentations on how to accomplish this using the App Engine, but nothing on the Compute Engine. Thank you!

Comment: did you manage to accomplish this task?

Comment: I ended up switching to another solution, good luck to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the Compute Engine application using the Cloud Deployment Manager API.
 https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager

The last line of the "bitbucket-pipelines.yml" file in this Atlassian blog post is "gcloud app deploy", to update the App Engine application. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-google-cloud-900820342.html

```
# Deploying the application
- gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml
```

For the Deployment Manager API, use "gcloud  deployment-manager deployments update". https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager/deployments/update

For example:

```
# Deploying the application
- gcloud -q deployment-manager deployments update my-deployment --config config.yaml
```

I recommend you have a look at the best practices for using the Deployment Manager API with CI/CD pipelines. https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices/#continuous_integration_ci_continuous_deployment_cd